# Problem in Nested Query

Tags: subquery, sqlite

I have a query like this

```
SELECT m.title
FROM Movie AS M
WHERE
(SELECT MAX(r.stars)
 FROM rating AS r
WHERE r.mID = M.mID);
```

I want to show the MAX(r.stars) in my result set, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What DB are you using? SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle, ...

Comment: SQLite. On Coursera

Comment: [Reposted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780339/give-nested-query-an-alias). [Don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already asked and answered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a sub query here. Does this give you what you need? If so it should be more efficient.

```
SELECT m.title, MAX(r.stars)
FROM Movie AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating AS r ON r.mID = m.mID;
GROUP BY m.title
```

Only way it could break that I can see is if you have two movies with the same title and different mID's.

Comment: Using `GROUP BY m.mID, m.title` would solve that. (not needed only if `m.title` has a unique constraint)

Comment: of course. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `WHERE` with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, or `INNER JOIN` if you only want movies with ratings.

```
SELECT m.title, r.MaxRating
FROM Movie AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT mID, MAX(r.stars) AS MaxRating
    FROM rating 
    GROUP BY mID
)AS r ON r.mID = M.mID;
```